# Use binding for registring a member function (multiple instances) in a C-Library as callback

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a C++ wrapper class for a given C-Library (open62541 - can't modify the source code). There are Datasource objects with callback functions for read / write notifications.

So now I want to create a Datasource with its own callback functions and they should be registered inside de C-Library. I was able to create a non static member function and bind the hidden this parameter, but if I create a new Datasource object, my previous registered callbacks are lost -> it is always used the last this parameter...

a minimal example (without the open62541 stuff):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct Callback;

template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
struct Callback<Ret(Params...)> {
    template <typename... Args> 
    static Ret callback(Args... args) {                    
        return func(args...);  
    }
    static std::function<Ret(Params...)> func; 
};


template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
std::function<Ret(Params...)> Callback<Ret(Params...)>::func;

// C-style API which just wants a standard function for callback
void c_function_which_wants_callback(int (*func)(int num1, int num2)) {}


class ClassWithCallback {
    public:

    ClassWithCallback() {
        Callback<int(int,int)>::func = std::bind(&ClassWithCallback::method_to_callback_read, &my_class, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
        callback_t readNofification = static_cast<callback_t>(Callback<int(int,int)>::callback);
            
        Callback<int(int,int)>::func = std::bind(&ClassWithCallback::method_to_callback_write, &my_class, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
        callback_t writeNofification = static_cast<callback_t>(Callback<int(int,int)>::callback);
        
        // passing the configuration sturcture to the library
        // Signatures are simplified (just used as example) -> c_function_which_wants_callback
        _valueBackend.backend.external.callback.userWrite = readNofification;
        _valueBackend.backend.external.callback.notificationRead = writeNofification;
        
        // Generate a instance specific variable
        srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
        guid = rand();
        print("%d", guid);
    }

    private:
        int guid;
    
    int method_to_callback_read(int num1, int num2) {
        // Do some stuff
        print("%d", guid);
        return 0;
    }
    int method_to_callback_write(int num1, int num2) {
        // Do some stuff
        print("%d", guid);
        return 0;
    }
};

typedef int (*callback_t)(int,int);

int main() {
    ClassWithCallback my_class_A;
    ClassWithCallback my_class_B;
    ClassWithCallback my_class_C;
}
```

The server (c-libary) will always use the "my_class_C" binding and all notifications are redirected to only one object... but I want separated callbacks.

Where is my fault?
Best regards
Patrick

I'm trying to bind different instance member functions to a given C-Callback function (variable read/write notifications).

Comment: When you made `Callback::func` static, you are just keep overwriting the same `func`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this C library's API is not compatible with C++. It's just not possible to take something that accepts only a single function pointer and turn it into something else that calls a class method. A properly-written C library API will allow registration of callbacks together with an opaque, pass-through pointer, which is easily adaptable to a C++ wrapper that turns the whole thing into a method call. Unfortunately, the shown C library API likes a pass-through `void *`, as such it cannot be conveniently used with C++.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep can you please give me a minimal example? I'm currently completly confused.
just changing the Callback::func to non-Static doesn't work, because binding and usage of my template structure won't work.